# How to OrderByKey and OrderByChild Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have item like this

```
 "category":    
     "Pria":
        "-kasjdwkivii":
             "count":"1"
             "name": "Jaket"
             "price": "25000"
       "-kwkiskdiooo":
             "count":"5"
             "name": "Jaket 2"
             "price": "35000"
```

i use pagination and example first my last key -kwkiskdiooo and success

and the next i want loadmore and should show -kasjdwkivii

how to sorting by count and then find key -kasjdwkivii and limit if the item more than 2

Answer (score 1):

firebase.database().ref('category/Pria').orderByKey().orderByChild('count')

Comment: Explain please!